# Extension Method of List<t> not recognize Instance method of the class C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, extension-methods

i have a contact class that i want to create a Extension method for a list of that class, but it's won't recognize my con.GetName() function.
I used right reffernce and it does recognize the class name, altough it won't recognize the instance methods of the class

```
public static string ToString (this List<Contact> Contacts)
{
    string str = "";
    foreach(Contact con Contacts)
    {
        str += con.GetName() + ", ";
    }
    return str.Substring(0, str.Length - 2);
}
```

EDIT: I Removed the  at the function line, but now there is another error, this time its mark the name of the function (ToString), i tried to change the name, but without any success or change.
now the GetName() working.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0051  Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'List<Contact>' is less accessible than method 'MyExtensions.ToString(List<Contact>)'    Whatsapp    D:\Whatsapp Versions\17.6\Whatsapp\ExtensionMethods.cs  100 Active
```

Comment: Show us the `GetName` method, and ensure you have the correct imports.

Comment: Why is this method generic? Note that `Contact` here is the **generic type parameter**, not your class `Contact`. Since you only care about `Contact`s, don't make the method generic. And worse: You will never be able to call this method like an extension, because `List<T>` like all types already defines an instance method named `ToSTring()` that will always be chosen over your extension.

Comment: @RenéVogt Well, since it's generic you could call it by specifying a type parameter, but as Sweeper says in their answer, it's not needed at all.

Comment: You can shorten your code: `return string.Join(", ", Contacts.Select(c => c.GetName()));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has at least two problems:

1. If you call your extension `ToString()` you will not be able to use it like an extension, because if you have a

   ```
   List<Contact> myContacts = ...
   Console.WriteLine(myContacts.ToString());
   ```

   the compiler will always choose the *instance method `ToString()` of the `List<T>` class instead of your extension.
2. You declared your method **generic** (`ToString<Contact>`) which is not necessary when you only want to accept `List<Contact>` here. Note that the `Contact` you wrote here is now the generic **type parameter** and not your `Contact` type. Thatswhy the compiler doesn't know the `GetName()` method: `con` is not of type `Contact`, but of the generic type not known at compile time.
3. I suggest to use `string.Join` instead of concatenating the strings "by hand":

So the final suggestions:

```
public static string AsString(this List<Contact> contacts) =>
     string.Join(", ", contacts.Select(c => c.GetName());
```

Comment: I remove the <Contact>, and the instance method do working fine, although after the removal the function line name making an error as i mentioned at the edit of the question . and i did also changed the name of the fuction

Answer (score 3):

Is this a typo? You accidentally wrote `<Contact>`:

```
public static string ToString <Contact>(this List<Contact> Contacts)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^
                               here
```

That makes `Contact` a generic type parameter, making your extension method work on any `List<T>`. Obviously you wan't be able to access `Contact`'s members because the list can be a list of anything. To fix this, remove the generic parameter:

```
public static string ToString(this List<Contact> Contacts)
```

Note that this extension method will not be chosen when you call it directly on a `List<Contact>` because `List` already has a `ToString` method (actually all classes do...). So the only way to call *your* `ToString` is `SurroundClass.ToString(someList)`. I suggest you rename the method.

Comment: I remove the <Contact>, and the instance method do working fine, although after the removal the function line name making an error as i mentioned at the edit of the question . and i did also changed the name of the fuction

Comment: @delex depending on your needs, change `Contact` to public or your method to `internal`.